# Github io page does not update

Tags: git, github, github-pages

I want to update my github.io page; however, after I using git to push the changes, I found there is no change on my github io page, and the content is still previous one. Then I found the default the branch is **main** branch. I always push changes on **master** branch. How could I fix it and update the content? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you provide the repo so we can see the commit history to further diagnose? Thanks.

Comment: Also, can you tells us how you're building the site. Is it jekyll, hugo, or standard HTML static pages.

Comment: Yes, sure. Here is the link: https://github.com/leo0807/leo0807.github.io/tree/master;

Comment: And I build the site by using HTML, SCSS and JS.

Comment: The latest change doesn't seem to indicate much differences: https://github.com/leo0807/leo0807.github.io/commit/8e46951b3272d57fee4ef62811e088880eea50c2

Comment: Looking at the source, I see this:
```
    </footer>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <script src="music.js"></script>
<!--      -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Note that the build as of right now says 22 minutes ago and you committed 28 minutes ago, so there was several minutes of lag: https://github.com/leo0807/leo0807.github.io/runs/1940431736

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the GitHub Pages, it built successfully and an inspection of the source showed the changes to index.html.

I saw this:

```
</footer>
<script src="script.js"></script>
<script src="music.js"></script>
<!-- --> </body>
</html>
```

in the index.html

This matches what is available in the latest commit: https://github.com/leo0807/leo0807.github.io/commit/8e46951b3272d57fee4ef62811e088880eea50c2

I believe the reason you didn't see it is the delay in publication. The build page says 25 min ago:
https://github.com/leo0807/leo0807.github.io/runs/1940431736

However your commit in relative is 32 minutes ago.

I hope this answers your question.